# Jsoup - test valid input body html with relative path

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this code:

```
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.relaxed();
String test = "<a href=\"index.html?Proxy-Remote-User=ABC1\">"
```

With Jsoup if I run

```
Jsoup.isValid(test, whitelist)
```

It returns false. I think it's because of a missing protocol. Is there a way to make it acceptable?

Comment: First off, your example is missing quotes. But my guess is that it's maybe because the closing tag (`</a>`) is missing?

Comment: I'm sure there's a workaround where you can add the absolute path to the beginning of the url before validating(incase you don't want to change the links manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Whitelist` is deprecated, use `Safelist` instead. Your assumption is right, the protocol is the issue. I think you **have** to use a full url(with http or https specified). I got it working with this:

```
test ="<a href=\"https:\\www.somesite\\index.html?Proxy-Remote-User=ABC1\">";
System.out.println("Is valid:"+Jsoup.isValid(test, safelist));
```

##### Output:

```
Is valid:true
```

Comment: `addProtocols("a","href","http");` is not necessary. The `relaxed` whitelist has them already defined as `addProtocols("a", "href", "ftp", "http", "https", "mailto")`.